# Use second router in separate building on same ethernet

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, wifi-configuration

I am based in the UK and we have a wifi network in our house. Our internet is provided by EE so we have an EE router.

We have an office in our back garden which I use for work which needs to have wifi as my wife i getting some equipment which requires wifi. I tried a wifi extender initially but it didn't seem to work great so we decided to run a cable from the ethernet port on the back of the EE router out to the office. There is a junction box in the office which I use to connect my laptop directly to the internet. I now need to add a wifi to the mix.

I've got a BT Home Hub router which I'd like to use for the office wifi. I found that plugging a cable from the junction box straight in to the connection of the BT Home Hub doesn't work. The blue broadband light stays orange and troubleshooting steps on the bt home hub page (192.168.1.254) does not work. I suspect this is because the we are sending the internet from the EE router from the Ethernet port and the home hub is not expecting an ethernet connection. Is this correct?

So then, going on the hunch that the BT Home Hub doesn't like the ethernet connection I tried plugging the cable from the junction box in the garden office in to ethernet connection on the BT Home Hub. Now what I get on visiting 192.168.1.254 is sometimes the bt home hub setup page and sometimes the EE page, which is to expected I suppose because they both to using that ip address.

So with all that said is there any way I can get this to work? I also have a nergear switch and not sure if that can be used in some way.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest extension method, which requires almost no user knowledge, is to use a WiFi **access point**.

This requires you to plug into the existing ethernet you managed to get across to the garden office, then needs no additional configuration beyond setting a password & encryption method. [WPA2 is the 'best' common home-security method, look for that capability.]

If your existing router[s] have an access point mode, this will be the cost-free choice, otherwise you can get a simple device for maybe 30 quid.

Your BT hub, for example, wants to see "the internet" on that input port, not another domestic router. It *might* be technically feasible to reconfigure, but ISP routers very rarely give you the freedom to do this. They tend to be locked down tight. Unless it is highly user-configurable then abandon that idea.
Alternatively, if your Netgear has an access-point mode, this might be leveraged into position, but you'd need to check the manual. Many non-ISP-supplied devices can be configured to become a simple access point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So something like this will enable me to run a cable from the junction box in to the office in to the device to give me WiFi ? TP-LINK TL-WA801N 300 Mbps Wireless N Access Point, Passive PoE Power Injector, 10/100M Ethernet Port https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B085M4ZJ2L/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_glc_fabc_3ZMFCHSNAFHC1CKGH7WC?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: Looks like the TP should be able to do it - Access point is listed as one of the modes - https://www.tp-link.com/uk/home-networking/access-point/tl-wa801n/ You just have to slog through the manual to figure out how to set it up. It should be pretty simple. Basically, access point mode lets your existing router handle all your internet connections, the access point just wants a password to connect, then hands off to the main router for everything else.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much for your help